# Rails 5 Api Only - Devise - react - simple_token_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf

I have a react front end and a rails 5 api only back end, and I'm trying to get the simple_token_authentication gem to work.  I am getting this error when I try to sign_in:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for 100.38.166.199 at 2017-05-05 02:31:24 +0000
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"test17@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"test17@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I suspect its related to CSRF.  I sometimes get the CSRF authenticity error message, but strangely not always

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

scope module: 'api' do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :properties
    end  
  end
end
```

My Application controller (which I have because I am also using ActiveAdmin)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, fallback_to_devise: false
end
```

This is what the post request looks like on the client side

```
export function signinUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch){

  //submit email password to the server
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/sign_in.json`, { email, password })
    .then(response => {
      //if request is good, update state to indicate user is authenticated
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER});
      //-save the jwt token
      localStorage.setItem('authentication_token', response.data.token);
      //-redirect route somewhere
      browserHistory.push('/test');
    })
    .catch( error => {
    //if request is bad, show an error to the user
    dispatch(authError(error));
    })

  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, fallback: :exception
```

Note that the `fallback: :none` or `fallback: :exception` syntax is preferred to `fallback_to_devise: false`.